# HTML prevent line break (between two table tags)

Tags: html, html-table, line-breaks

I have following code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Very unfortunately, a line break is inserted between these two tables. I have tried putting them both in a single span and setting the whitespace to nowrap, but at no avail. Please, could you tell me how I can simply put these elements in a single row, without setting the float attribute in CSS and without surrounding each table with a `<td> {table} </td>` and then putting this in a table row.

Thanks a lot in advance. I have asked Google, but it just wouldn't say anything ^^ StackOverflow remained silent so far, too

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found it!

One has to use the following settings for both tables:

```
display: inline-table;
```

Thanks for the inline, guys, thanks a lot, but at least, inline-table works ^^

Hope I helped...

Comment: Did anyone noticed that display: inline-table keeps the table in one group ? It does not split across multiple pages.

Answer (score 1):

According to the **CSS box model :**

> margin values do not apply to table rows and table cells See:
> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties
>
> padding and border values do not apply to table rows but apply to
> table cells See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties

A quick fix is to add padding to the top of the table that you want to separate.

> For example: https://codepen.io/Gh-_-st/pen/oGKOQL

```
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr class="row1">
        <td>Row One - 1</td>
        <td>Row One - 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row2">
        <td>Row Two - 1</td>
        <td>Row Two - 2</td>
    </tr>    
   </table>
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table-2">
        <tr class="row1">
            <td>Row One - 1</td>
            <td>Row One - 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row2">
            <td>Row Two - 1</td>
            <td>Row Two - 2</td>
        </tr>    
   </table>
```

> CSS:

```
     td {
       border: 1px dotted blue;
     }

     .table-2 {
      padding-top: 40px;
    }

    td {
      padding : 20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you float table 1 to the left, and table to to the right?  By default, tables are "block" elements, so you could try display:inline.

Comment: Making things line up: Float them to the same side, not to left-right. It will often just make everything else around so much harder to get right.

Answer (score 0):

or this:

```
<table border=1 style="position:absolute;width:100;height:30;left:0;top:100"> 
<tr> 
<td>aaaaa</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
<table border=1 style="position:absolute;width:100;height:30;left:100;top:100"> 
<tr> 
<td>bbbbb</td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`table{display:inline;}` didn't work?

Comment: nope. does not work. Although it is in one line, the table borders are cutting its content. It's totally wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: This answer is very old, and new, better techniques exist today.

**Original content:**

You should use CSS for this, as it is a presentational issue. Why can't you use CSS?

This is how I'd do it. Simple, works in every browser and it easily adapts to surrouding layout elements. Give both tables a width that fits them in the containing element, and float both of them to the left. For example:

```
<div id="container">
  <table>...</table>
  <table>...</table>
</div>

#container { width: 500px; } 
table { width: 250px; float: left; }
```

Comment: I can use CSS. I just did not want to make one table float left and the otehr one float right, but your solution seems interesting. I'll try it out now. Thanks ^

Comment: Yep, I see. As i stated in a previous comment, floating left-right often complicates things around, and makes the layout very little adaptable to surrounding content. Floating things to the same side is better.

Comment: `float` in general opens up a can of worms that can be hard to deal with. Floating elements tend to necessitate hacks upon hacks to keep them from breaking other parts of the layout. `display: inline-block` (or `inline-table` as in accepted answer) is *much* easier to work with.

Comment: Added an update to the post. Floating was indeed the way to go once. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table style="display:inline">
    <tr>
        <td>Table 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table style="display:inline">
    <tr>
        <td>Table 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<table style="display:inline">
    <tr>
        <td>Table 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table style="display:inline">
    <tr>
        <td>Table 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could explain your code a bit instead of only pasting it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this css:

```
table {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
```

Or you can hack into negative top-margin

```
table{
  margin-top:-20px;
}
```